# Edit SCM configuration in a WorkflowJob

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Any idea how I can update or configure the scm configruation when it comes to workflowjob (simple pipeline not freestyle) ?

we can access the pipeline scm configuration using : .getSCMs() method on the job
my problem is that the SCMs field is read only and everything I tried failed in changing that object. All i can do is read the existing info.

for example for multibranch i was able to update the field easily using similar code to below and .getSCMSources()
for freestle project it s even simpler and there is a direct setter

I am pretty sure that the class workflowjob cant be without a way to set the scms, more so that using the ui i can edit the job and save it. how does that translate to code for example ?

My script is very long so i ll focus on just the part i need

For example i tried multiple ways of building another list of scms and set it in the old one

```
if (project instanceof WorkflowJob ) {
    println "is simple pipeline"
    def newSourceList = []

    project.getSCMs().each{ scm -> newSourceList.add(doSomethingWithScm(scm))}
    project.SCMs.removeAll()
    
    project.SCMs = newSourceList // error readonly
    // newSourceList.each { scm -> project.SCMs << scm } doesnt work either
    println "Done !"
}
```

The scm is of type GitSCM

The doSomethingWithScm() method basically returns a new gitSCM object based on the old scm configuration for each project (no issue there)

I tried also playing with userRemoteConfigs within the scm itself to update the fields i want. I didnt succeed either

Comment: You didn't mention why you want to change the `scm` object. Regardless, you can turn off default checkout and then `checkout my_modified_scm` instead.

Comment: yeah sorry, in my use case, i dont need to checkout a different scm in a job. I need to update all the job (thousands) in my jenkins. i got all kind of jobs andI need to update the creds and url of each project from github to another platform

Comment: Well there is a really easy workaround. Iterating over the config.xml in the job folder and sed everytime to update the url link
I m keeping this open though because  i am curious if there is a setter for scm in normal pipeline

Comment: Any operation you would do to `scm` object inside a pipeline would not result in getting that change written to the configuration of the job anyway. It would only affect that particular run. Updating `config.xml` is the way to go.

Comment: i am not doing it inside a pipeline, it s inside groovy script console to edit all the job once. it works for all my other jobs except normal pipeline. but yes i will update the config.xml